# The category $\operatorname{Fun}(\sf{C},\sf{A})$ is abelian is $\sf{A}$ is abelian and $\sf{C}$ is small. Why the set-theoretic condition?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

Proposition 1.4.4 in F. Borceux *Handbook of Categorical Algebra II* says that if $\sf{A}$ is an abelian category and $\sf{C}$ is a small category, then the category of functors $\operatorname{Fun}(\sf{C},\sf{A})$ is abelian.

I have two questions:

1. Is this true without demanding $\sf{C}$ to be small? The only place where Borceux proof seem to demand this condition is where he uses that in this case limits and colimits are computed pointwise. But I think I know how to prove that products, kernels and cokernels are computed pointwise without demanding $\sf{C}$ to be small.
2. If the theorem is true without this condition, then why aren't limits and colimits computed pointwise in functor categories without this assumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathcal{C}$ is not small, the functor category $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{A})$ will not be locally small in general. The morphisms in this category are natural transformations, whose components are indexed in $\operatorname{Ob}\mathcal{C}$, which is a proper class/large set if $\mathcal{C}$ is **not** small. Thus $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{A})$ cannot be $\mathsf{Ab}$-enriched and hence cannot be abelian.

Comment: What if you widen the definition of Abelian categories such that “locally large” categories are considered to be Abelian if their homomorphism sets form a (possibly large) Abelian group?

Comment: In this case I don’t know of any obstruction. But tbh this case didn’t occur to me yet.

Comment: Could you explain why if $\sf{C}$ is not small then $\operatorname{Fun}(\sf{C},\sf{A})$ is not locally small?

Comment: I made an edit. Does it help?

Comment: @PrudiiArca it does indeed. But then I wonder the converse: why is the category of functors locally small if $\sf{C}$ is small? Is it clear? I am a noob dealing with set theory haha

Comment: It is relatively clear, if you are familiar with elementary cardinality arguments (which you may wish to familiarise yourself to get a better grasp of what is going on). As for allowing locally large categories, there are delicate issues at play but it is a well-known situation. In particular, one can employ Grothendieck universes so that that small and large become relative to a given universe. If $C$ is in universe $K$, then the functor category will be at most locally in universe $K+1$.

Comment: So am I :) Well if $\mathcal{C}$ is small it means that $\operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ is a small set, so natural transformations are indeed indexed by a small set. The point is that given a small set $I$ and a family $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ the product $\Prod \limits_{i\in I} X_i$ is again a set. Natural transformations are elements of such a set (where $X_i = \mathcal{C}(Fi,Gi)$ for $i\in \operatorname{Ob}\mathcal{C}$) satisfying some conditions.

Answer (score 2):

It is "merely" a problem of formalities.
Borceux mentions both the universe axiom and Gödel-Bernays (NBG) set theory as solutions to the problem of working with large categories, but they are *not* equally powerful.
Borceux's definition of "category" requires that the collection of objects is a class and that the collection of all morphisms between any two objects is a set – so he is implicitly working in NBG.
Thus, in this definition, there are two obstructions to forming the category of all functors $\mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ when $\mathcal{A}$ is not small:

1. The collection of all functors $\mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ is so big that it is not even a class!
   If it were a class, then a functor $\mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ would be a set, since a set is defined to be a collection that is a member of some class.
   But then we could use the axiom of replacement to deduce that the class of objects of $\mathcal{A}$ is a set – contradiction.
2. The collection of natural transformations between two functors $\mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ is also too big to be a class, let alone a set, by the same argument.

That said, these are not serious problems.
If one uses the universe axiom instead of NBG then there is a more appropriate definition of "category" that permits the formation of functor categories between any two categories.
All the basic theorems hold, so if $\mathcal{B}$ has limits of a certain shape then limits of that shape exist and are computed componentwise in the category of all functors $\mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$, etc.
In particular, if $\mathcal{B}$ is an abelian category then the category of all functors $\mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ is also abelian.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ZhenLin. Do you know some reference which discuss this more appropriate definition of category using universes?

Comment: It's in _Categories for the working mathematician_.